# How to get all the selected items in a table?

Tags: datatable, jsf-2, primefaces

i have a problem with the datatable component. I want to create a datatable with checkbox like a multiple selection example on primefaces showcase. This is the code:

```
<p:dataTable id="table_cats" value="#{fooBean.catsList}" var="cat" selectionMode="single"   selection="#{fooBean.selectedCatsToDelete}">
<p:column selectionMode="multiple">
    <f:facet name="header">Remove</f:facet>
</p:column>
<p:column>
    <f:facet name="header">Cat Name</f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="#{cat.name}" />
    </p:column></p:dataTable>
```

So, the problem is when a select an item. I don't know how to get all the selected items in the table. Can anyone help me with this problem?

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5563498/how-to-do-multiple-selection-in-jsf-or-primefaces-datatable

Comment: No, the question here is that this example doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not quite clear what your comment means "this example doesn't work". Are there any errors? Or is `selectedCatsToDelete` empty?

First guess would be the `selectionMode="single"` in your `<p:dataTable>` versus `selectionMode="multiple"` in the column.

Try to remove the attribute from your table tag.

Answer (score 1):

They are all set in the property behind `#{fooBean.selectedCatsToDelete}` and they are thus accessible in any action/listener method which you have hooked to some command link/button.

E.g.

```
<p:commandButton value="Remove" action="#{bean.remove}" />
```

with

```
public void remove() {
    someService.remove(selectedCatsToDelete); // JSF has already put the selected items in selectedCatsToDelete.
}
```